# Created by field in a user's sub class

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I need to have a "created_by" field in the sub user model which will show the User, who created Translator's account (is_translator=True).

User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_client = models.BooleanField('Client status', default=False)
    is_translator = models.BooleanField('Translator status', default=False)
```

Sub user:

```
class Translator(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an extra [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

```
class Translator(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'is_translator': True}
        primary_key=True
    )
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='created_translators'
    )
```

In the view(s) where you create a `Translator`, you will then need to fill in the `created_by` field with the logged in user (`request.user`).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).